# Tcl: best way to test for empty list

Tags: tcl

Sorry, that's a very trivial question, but it seems to be so trivial that I can't find any recommendation: What is the best way in Tcl to test whether a list is empty? I would go for `if {$myList eq ""} ...`, or is there a better way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I use `[llength $myList] == 0`.

Comment: @Shawn: Isn't that inefficient if the list is long? Or does Tcl store the precomputed length of the list internally?

Comment: I certainly hope it does that. And it avoids the potential cost of converting to a string.

Comment: @Shawn: I wonder how one could find out. `tcl::unsupported::representation` doesn't show any precomputed list length or string length values. It also shows different results for `{1 2 3}` (a "pure string") and `[list 1 2 3]` (a list without internal string representation). Empty lists seem to be a "pure string".

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about what the representation is beforehand; Tcl will change those as it sees fit. (The output of `representation` is _deliberately_ a bit awkward for tooling to parse; it's for debugging, not type decisions!)

Comment: Note that `$myList eq ""` is not even equivalent to `[llength $myList] == 0`.  E.g. if myList contains a single space, it is not equal to "" but when treated as a list its length will be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *know* you have a list (because you've made it that way or are using other operations that treat the value as such), the best empty check is looking at the `llength` of it to see if it is zero. I usually prefer to use the result as if it was boolean, like this, but comparing to zero also works just fine.

```
if {[llength $theList]} {
    puts "the list is NOT empty"
} else {
    puts "the list IS empty"
}
```

Yes, this will incur the cost of converting the value to a list, but that conversion is cached within the value itself (this is a type of “internal representation”) so the next operation to use it as a list is then much faster as it doesn't have to reparse anything.

Comment: You're right (and Shawn as well). My solution (`if {$myList eq ""} ...`) is *much* slower. I'll post the test as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share some test code which shows that `if {$myList eq ""}...` can be *much* slower than `if {![llength $myList}} ...`:

```
set repeats 10
foreach n {10 100 1000 10000 20000} {
    puts "n = $n"
    puts [time {
        set l [list]
        for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
            lappend l $i
        }
    } $repeats]  
    puts [time {
        set l [list]
        for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
            lappend l $i
            if {![llength $l]} {
                puts "empty (llength)"
            }
        }
    } $repeats]  
    puts [time {
        set l [list]
        for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
            lappend l $i
            if {$l eq ""} {
                puts "empty (eq)"
            }
        }
    } $repeats]
}
```

Here is the output; for each value of `n`: baseline (no check), check with `llength`, check with `eq`:

```
n = 10
5.0 microseconds per iteration
14.1 microseconds per iteration
14.0 microseconds per iteration
n = 100
40.6 microseconds per iteration
44.0 microseconds per iteration
105.8 microseconds per iteration
n = 1000
374.4 microseconds per iteration
440.7 microseconds per iteration
6240.1 microseconds per iteration
n = 10000
3534.4 microseconds per iteration
4485.8 microseconds per iteration
667206.0 microseconds per iteration
n = 20000
7576.7 microseconds per iteration
9051.9 microseconds per iteration
2761285.3 microseconds per iteration
```

I would guess that the solution using `if {$l eq ""}...` is very slow since does a conversion from a list to a string every time the check is done. Or is there a different explanation?

Comment: It depends on the internal representation. In your benchmark you add elements to the list using `lappend`, which modifies the internal representation to list. Testing by list operations then utilizes that representation. If appending by string methods instead the internal representation becomes string, and testing by string operations is faster, as testing by list operation would trigger change of internal representation. In essence, be consistent about your variable "types" and Tcl will reward you for it.